# Create buffer around spatial data in R

Tags: r, buffer, shapes, spatial

I have a spatial dataset of shopping centers that I would like to create buffers around in R.

I think these packages will be useful:

```
require(maptools)
require(geosphere)
```

I was able to do so for a set of coordinates, but not for spatial data. The code looks like this:

```
coordinates(locs) <- c("Longitude", "Latitude")  # set spatial  coordinates
fivekm <- cbind(coordinates(locs), X=rowSums(distm (coordinates(locs)[,1:2], fun = distHaversine) / 1000 <= 5)) # number of points within 5 km
```

But I don't know what function/package to use for a set of polygons. Can someone please advise on the function (or code) and I will go from there?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only option at the moment is to project your longitude and latitude points to a flat map and then do everything there. As far as I know there are no packages for doing polygonal geometry on the sphere yet (I'm working on one, but there is no ETA).

Projection used to be done with `spTransform` from the `sp` package, but now it may be more convenient to use the more modern simple features package `sf` which has the function `st_transform`. The vignette https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html has a section called "Coordinate reference systems and transformations" to help you with this part. The buffering is described in the section "Geometrical operations".

Comment: Thanks! @Ege Rubak.

Answer (score 4):

In library `rgeos`, there is the `gBuffer` function that works with SpatialPoints or SpatialPolygons.
The `width` parameter allows to set the distance to which you want to buffer. However, be careful, this distance is in the scale of the coordinates system used. Thus, in degrees and not in meters with non-projected data. As suggested by @Ege Rubak, you will have to project your data with `spTransform` first (be sure to use the appropriate CRS according to your location).
As for now, `rgeos` library works with library `sp`, but not (yet?) with the recent `sf`.

Answer (score 0):

The two previous post have covered the details but I thought it might be helpful to provide a workflow.  This is assuming you have you are using points of lat and long.  What is your original spatial data format?

1. Convert your coordinates into a Spatial Points Dataframe `SpatialPointsDataFrame` and assign it a geographic CRS (proj4) that matches your coordinate data (probably WGS84)
2. Change the projection to a local projected CRS with preferred units
3. Apply buffer to spatial point data frame, the `width` will now be in more usable units